# CRM software for a small non-profit

Tags: crm

I'm looking for CRM software for an international non-profit search and rescue team. The main reason for it is to run the media for the team when they are on a mission. I have looked at the following options and rejected each one:

- Highrise (monthly cost too expensive because each member of the team would need an account because we don't know who will have to take on which role when a mission happens. The probable cost was $45 per month which averaged over the time between missions would add up to the cost of losing one team member every two missions).
- Capsule CRM (again too costly)
- CiviCRM (this appears to lack a drop box for emails which is essential in making sure that team members actually use the system)

I have also looked at SugarCRM and Salesforce. Does anyone know of a CRM solution that would cost less than US$10 per month but which would include an email dropbox system like Highrise or Capsule CRM.

Comment: *"The main reason for it is to run the media for the team when they are on a mission."* - What does that mean?  Why do you need a CRM (customer relations management) system for search and rescue missions?  I'm only asking to help better find you a solution that fits your needs.  :)

Comment: @an Turner: You should award the bounty to the answer you think is best, or your 200 reps will evaporate and be wasted. If no answer helps at all, add a dummy answer, accept it and award it the bounty. You will not get the reps back, but it least you have made your statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know, if you have enough credentials to showcase urs as a non profit organisation, salesforce can give you and your team a free access.

FOr NGO's salesforce does not charge a penny.Please lemme know if you are interested.

Comment: I have looked at Salesforce, but it just seemed too complicated for our team and I couldn't see dropbox functionality. One of the problems is I don't want to spend time training members how to use the tool when we really struggle to have enough time to train for out Search and Rescue activities so I was looking for something which would be really simple to keep up to date without team members having to remember to log in to another system. If you think Salesforce can do this then I'd happily try it.

Answer (score 3):

There is also ZOHO CRM.

But what about Google Docs & Spreadsheet for sharing data? That is not a CRM, but works great and is free.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by run the media, however, if Email management is your main issue, you may want to take a look at a system such as [RT](http://bestpractical.com/rt/), [OTRS](http://otrs.org/demo/), [OSticket](http://osticket.com/) or [Cerberus](http://www.cerberusweb.com/).

Whist these are all helpdesk solutions, I think they may achieve what you want.

As for hosting, many of these should be able to be hosted either on a cheap standard hosting package, or at the extreme, a very low powered shared server - should easily be able to find one in your budget.

Comment: Would the big, open-source CRM system you're trying to think of happen to be [RT (Request Tracker)](http://bestpractical.com/rt/)?

Comment: @Jeremy W. Sherman - YES!!! Thanks, was driving me mad! I am looking through your previous answers and will give you a few upvotes where I think they are deserved!

Answer (score 1):

See Wikipedia page : [List of ERP software packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ERP_software_packages#Free_and_Open_Source_ERP_software).

It's missing :

[CK-ERP](http://ck-erp.org/drupal/)
[DYNAMIC 3i FREE EDITION](http://sdc.ca/free/)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use something like redmine to set up projects and process emails from team members automatically. Since its open source and built on ruby, you should be able to customize it to your specific needs (of course, that depends on your specific needs).

I am not sure what media you would want to handle using this (just emails or any other specific formats)

redmine url : http://www.redmine.org

handling emails : http://www.redmine.org/wiki/1/RedmineReceivingEmails#Target-project

hope this helps

Cheers/Raj K

Answer (score 1):

If you can not find what you are looking for this org is a non-profit supplier of software and services that provide free and greatly discounted products, advice, forums and help services.
http://home.techsoup.org/pages/about.aspx
Here is the 1st paragraph of their description of themselves.
TechSoup.org offers nonprofits a one-stop resource for technology needs by providing free information, resources, and support. In addition to online information and resources, we offer a product philanthropy service called TechSoup Stock. Here, nonprofits can access donated and discounted technology products, generously provided by corporate and nonprofit technology partners
This company may be ok for you.
https://www.akubocrm.com/non-profit.php